# Why is my video not playing in safari webbrowser?

Tags: html, html5-video

Hello everyone I have a problem with this code:

```
<div class="small-mobile-container">
                    <div class="mobv">
                        
                    
                    <video style="position:sticky "; preload="true", playsinline  , autoplay="autoplay" muted loop>
                        <source src="Pictures/Video 1.mp4"  />
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                      </video>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The problem is that it is not playing in the Safari web browser.
I tried a bunch of solutions but nothing helped. I don't know even why but there's a button which I can press, and then the video starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** Try using a **full path** to video. **(2)** Also rename your MP4 file name to **not have spaces**.

Code should be something like this:

```
<div class="small-mobile-container">
<div class="mobv">

<video preload="true" playsinline="" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" style="position:sticky; width: 100%; height: auto;" >
<source src="https://mywebsite.com/Pictures/Video_1.mp4"  />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried both solutions. It only not works for web safari on desktop . I cannot understand why this happen.